# how can I do the paste in vim without troubled by indent issue

Tags: vim

```
aaa
        bbb
        ccc
ddd
```

When I using copy the above lines from a file and pasted by "right click the mouse and select paste option and left click the mouse" into a file under edit by Vim in the insert mode, I get
the following:

```
aa
        bbb
                ccc
                ddd
```

I think it is due to some indent related settings in Vim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before pasting, do `:set paste`.  Afterward, do `:set nopaste`.  See `:help paste` for more details.

Comment: Ah I always forget about this because I'm so used to having system clipboard support. This is good if you don't have it and don't want to recompile, or perhaps if you're pasting from a tmux clipboard or similar that Vim isn't tied into.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Agreed, the system clipboard is better when available, but 1) it doesn't work in PuTTY etc. as you point out, and 2) my fingers have "Alt-Space-E-P" ingrained for pasting in a DOS box. :)

Comment: I think they should have an automatic mode for this. If the text is coming so fast that it can't possibly be a human being typing, then don't indent. (The mode will only last over a single `vi` insertion command until the terminating `ESC`).

Answer (score 3):

This is because what you're doing is essentially like just typing the text into Vim character-by-character, and so it does everything it would normally do.

The `*` register represents the system clipboard, so you can paste from it like so:

```
"*p
```

This assumes your Vim is compiled with support for the system clipboard. You can test if it is by running `vim --version | grep '+clipboard'`.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, why can that be? (I'm in a gnome-terminal on Arch Linux). It aborts the command at *

Answer (score 0):

`:set paste` before pasting, then `:set nopaste` afterward to restore normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:set paste` and `:set nopaste` to toggle paste mode.

In addition, you can use key combinations to make it easier. Update your .vimrc config file:

`let mapleader = ","`  "map leader to do extra combination.

`map <leader>pp :setlocal paste!<cr>`

Now when you can input `,pp` to toggle paste mode on and off.

Answer (score 0):

I have this on my .vimrc

`set pastetoggle=<f5> "for better pasting from clipboard`

You can use F5 to active the paste toggle and F5 to disable it.

Answer (score -2):

Or just put vim into insert mode (press *a* or *i*) before you "right click the mouse and select past option and left click the mouse".

The first "a" in your paste is doing that and so not being included in the paste.

Comment: True, might not get the indent bit, add :set noai and it probably would.

Comment: Nope, because `smartindent` could also be on.